# 'str' object has no attribute - imported file object not recognizing one of its methods?

Tags: python

I have been fiddling around trying to make a personal organizer. Each day is rendered as an object containing the number of hours spent on several given activities. It also, ideally, allows the user to save this info to a file and to import from previous entries.

Here is the code:

```
class Day:

def __init__(self, date, hours, python, math, story, phil, medi):

    self.date = int(date)
    self.hours = float(hours)
    self.python = float(python)
    self.math = float(math)
    self.story = float(story)
    self.phil = float(phil)
    self.medi = float(medi)

def getDay(self):
    return repr((self.date, self.hours, self.python, self.math, self.story, self.phil, self.medi))

def getDayList(self):
    return list(self.date, self.hours, self.python, self.math, self.story, self.phil, self.medi)




def getInfo():

#the following allows the user to import an existing file with one object per line

question = input("Enter new information or import an existing file(new/imp)")

if question[0] == "i" or question[0] == "I":

    fileName = input("What is the name of the file you would like to import?")

    inFile = open(fileName, "r")



    dayList = []

    for line in inFile:

        dayList.append(line)

    print(dayList)


    return dayList


    inFile.close()



#the following allows the user to write objects to a new file or append objects to an existing file
#though I have not tested the latter feature

elif question[0] == "n" or question[0] == "N":

    question2 = input("Would you like to append this new info to an existing file or write it to a new file(a/w)? Hit blank ente to exit")
    fileName = input("Enter filename for new information")
    outFile = open(fileName, question2)

    dayList = []   
    while question2 != "":

        date = input("Please enter date (in single string)")
        hours = input("please enter total hours for the day")
        python = input("please enter total hours of python")
        math = input("please enter total hours of math")
        story = input("please enter total hours of story writing")
        phil = input("please enter total hours of philosophy")
        medi = input("please enter total hours of meditation")

        #creates object
        dayObject = Day(date, hours, python, math, story, phil, medi)
        dayList.append(dayObject)
        question2 = input("Would you ;like to enter more info now (enter 'yes' or hit blank enter to conclude)")

    #writes each object to the file
    for item in dayList:

        print(item, file=outFile)


    return dayList

    outFile.close()



def main():


dayList = getInfo()

test = dayList[0]

print(test)

print(test.getDay())


main()
```

When I create a new file, I can use methods on the object: getDay(), for example, returns the various aspects of the class (date, hours, python, etc.). When I import the same file using the code in the first half of the getInfo() function, however, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rainydaycart/Documents/po2.py", line 101, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/rainydaycart/Documents/po2.py", line 98, in main
print(test.getDay())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getDay'
```

When I print the newly made object it appears to be an object and not a string. Why can't I execute the getDay() method, which is part of the class definition, when I import the same object from the file?

p.s. indents appear to be a little screwey in this post with the function heads(modules?), but they are not a problem when I run the file.

Comment: if you enter `i`, `dayList` is a list of strings, because that's what `getInfo()` returns in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something like -

```
for item in dayList:
    print(item, file=outFile)
```

You are not actually writing the objects, you are just writing the `str(object)` for it , and in your case, since your class does not define `__str__()` or `__repr__()` , it would be writing -

```
<__main__.Day object at 0x00260F10>
```

Simple Example to show this -

```
>>> class CA:
...     pass
...
>>> with open('a.txt','w') as f:
...     print(c,file=f)
...
```

File at the end contains -

```
<__main__.CA object at 0x00260F10>
```

---

What you actually want to use is - [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module for object serialization and deserialization.

Then you can write an object to file using [`pickle.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) and load it using - [`pickle.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) .

Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     pass
...
>>> c = CA()
>>> c.x = 10
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('a.txt','wb') as f:
...     pickle.dump(c,f)
...
>>> del c
>>> with open('a.txt','rb') as f:
...     d = pickle.load(f)
...
>>> d
<__main__.CA object at 0x007150F0>
>>> d.x
10
```

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, shouldn't it be:

```
def main():
    object = Day()
    dayList = object.getInfo()
    test = dayList[0]
```

Also, your `outFile.close()` and `inFile.close()` don't ever hit, as they are after the `return()`.

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that.